# Did Brian Finch break the fourth wall?

Tags: character, limitless, limitless-tv

In the TV adaptation of the movie Limitless, they introduced a new character named Brian Finch. Throughout the series, Finch constantly speaks with the audience, trying to communicate with the audience.

There was a similar manner in the movie when Morra seems to say his life story to the audience, but Finch seems to go further and try to interact with the audience. Now, he never shows any indication (as far as I remember), that he knows him being a character in a TV show, but without going that deep, he always tries to talk to the audience. unlike Morra did, which is more similar to telling his story.

So everything combined Finch did, can it be considered that Brian Finch really did break the fourth wall?

Comment: I'm looking for Executive Producer confirmation, before I make an answer, but I would say he did. Even when I look it up on Google, most reviewers comment on him doing so.

Comment: Especially "Brain Finch's Black Ops" Episode, I'm pretty sure he directly talked to the audience there.

Comment: I don't understand the question: I haven't watched the series, but isn't a character acknowledging/talking directly to the audience the very definition of breaking the fourth wall? https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BreakingTheFourthWall

Comment: @Luciano there are few instances where I think it's not exactly clear. He talks to the audience, but he doesn't exactly acknowledge that's what he's doing and times where maybe it's like he's talking to himself for the audience's benefit, but I feel certain he more ardently broke the 4th wall on several other occasions, so it does seem moot, unless a particular instance is being looked at.

Comment: @DarthLocke He constantly gave out mixed-feelings about that, IMO. before posted here, I did lil googling and found few of similar reviews, but they weren't giving out much credibility to their opinions

Comment: @Luciano as Locke said, show is not clear on Finch's intentions. sometimes it illustrated that Finch is spitting out his mind for us, similar to someone narrating the story, sometimes he just talks to himself, sometimes he talks to audience and/or someone else around him or some imaginary character. (he has several copies of himself he even used to talk to).. so tl;dr; it's complicated

Comment: If "sometimes he talks to audience", isn't he clearly breaking the 4th wall in these occasion? Or do you want to know if he is breaking the 4th wall *every single time* he seems to speak alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## **Yes, He did.**

## **Confirmation from Executive Producer Craig Sweeny Speaking with [IndieWire](https://www.indiewire.com/2015/09/limitless-the-tv-show-might-be-a-cbs-procedural-but-its-weird-and-smart-and-fun-57611/):**

> “I do write whatever the weirdest thing on procedural TV is at any
> given moment,” he said when Indiewire spoke with him after the
> screening. “‘Medium’ was very strange and ‘Elementary’ had some very
> high-concept episodes as well, so I know how to inject that into a CBS
> show. There was a talking fetus in the first episode and no one said,
> ‘Take out the talking fetus.’ **We have breaking the fourth wall and
> singing in the second episode** and they’re not telling us to take it
> out. They’re saying they like it. So, for now anyway, they’re letting
> us have fun.”

## **Consensus from Recaps/Reviews:**

#### **[Vulture](https://www.vulture.com/2015/11/limitless-recap-season-1-episode-7.html) - *Brian Finch's Black Ops* - Recap**

> Things get a little weird, though, when mysterious men break into
> Brian’s apartment, **interrupt his fourth-wall-breaking monologue**, Tase
> him, and kidnap him. “Oh, that’s not how it goes,” he notes.

#### **[TV.com](http://www.tv.com/news/limitless-brian-finchs-black-op-review-life-comes-at-you-fast-144659952341/) - *Brian Finch's Black Ops* - Recap**

> And, thankfully, the episode did the smart thing by paying respect to
> Ferris, especially with that familiar opening sequence, without diving
> too far into shot-for-shot remake territory. This tactic was helped a
> great deal by the fact that Limitless already employed a variety of
> devices to get Brian talking to himself; **stretching that a bit further
> to a couple fourth-wall breaking nods** to young Mr. Bueller only added
> to Brian's shaggy dog charm off the NZT.

#### **[i09](https://io9.gizmodo.com/on-limitless-everybodys-robotic-arms-go-on-a-crime-spr-1744607926) - *Arm-ageddon* - Recap**

> So to catch the arm hacker, Brian uses NZT to become a hacker himself.
> (“Did you hack the New York Stock Exchange...?” is a sentence that
> escapes Rebecca’s mouth at one point.) **While Brian’s breaking the
> fourth wall** making fun of “hackers at work” montages in TV shows and
> movies, he doesn’t subject us to rapid vignettes of overly determined
> typing; instead, we get Vines of cats.

#### **[IGN](https://www.ign.com/articles/2015/11/04/limitless-brian-finchs-black-op-review) - *Brian Finch's Black Ops* - Review**

> After a decidedly serious episode last week, Limitless steered back
> into more comedic territory with a full-on Ferris Bueller homage,
> complete with character references, fourth-wall breaking monologues
> and music from the 1986 film.

## **[No Fourth Wall](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoFourthWall) - TV Trope Listed Under *Limitless* at [tvtropes.org](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Series/Limitless)**

> Some series can go their entire lives without breaking the Fourth Wall
> once. Some series will occasionally break the Fourth Wall for a few
> moments of comedy, but outside of that the Fourth Wall is in full
> effect.
>
> And then there are these.
>
> **A series with No Fourth Wall doesn't just break the fourth wall, it
> vaporizes it. There might as well not be one. Characters will make
> references to "the last episode" or "next issue". They'll criticize
> the production, writing, management or even the audience.** In extreme
> cases, they'll refuse to go on acting. Expect there to be large
> amounts of Medium Awareness, such as characters in a comic pointing
> out the use of panels. No Fourth Wall often leads to characters being
> extremely Genre Savvy, or frequent lampshading of Genre Blindness.